# How to configure a one-to-many referencing same principal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a `Message` which can have many threads. I call the *thread* a `MessageThread`. A `MessageThread` really only encapsulates the *thread owner* (`Message`) and a response, also a *`Message`*.

```cs
public class Message {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    
    // other properties
    
    public ICollection<MessageThread> Threads {get; set;}
}

public class MessageThread {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Message Owner {get; set;}
    public int ThreadId {get; set;}
    public virtual Message Thread {get; set;}
}

//  EntityFramework configurations
public class MessageConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Message> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Message> builder) {
        builder.HasMany(message => message.Threads)
            .WithOne(messageThread => messageThread.Thread)
            .HasForeignKey(message => message.Id);
    }

}

public class MessageThreadConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MessageThread> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MessageThread> builder) {
        builder.HasOne(messageThread => messageThread.Thread)
            .WithMany(message => message.Threads)
            .HasForeignKey(messageThread => messageThread.ThreadId);
    }
}
```

... here is the method that saves to the database:

```cs
public async Task<Message> CreateThreadAsync(int parentId, Message threadMessage, IEnumerable<Tag> tags, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    //  create the message record
    threadMessage = await CreateMessageAsync(threadMessage, tags, cancellationToken);

    using (var context = new DataContext()) {
        context.Messages.Attach(threadMessage);

        //  query parent message
        var parentMessage = await context.Messages
            .Where(message => message.Id == parentId)
            .Include(message => message.Threads)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (parentMessage.Threads == null) {
            parentMessage.Threads = new List<MessageThread>();
        }

        parentMessage.Threads.Add(new MessageThread() {
            Owner = parentMessage,
            Thread = threadMessage
        });

        await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    return threadMessage;
}
```

The individual messages are saved as expected (see image). However, see the `MessageThreads` table (*circled*) just below:
[image]

How can I fix the relationship so that `ThreadId` references the correct message? In this case, `2`.

**Expectations**
Assume the following messages:
[image]

...then the message threads would be:
[image]

This is a `One-to-Many` relationship between `Message` and `MessageThread`. Am I configuring it properly?

Comment: The entity `MessageThread` has a property `OwnerId` which references a `Message`, but also have a property `Thread` with reference a `Message` too as well? Can you elaborate on that? Also explain what "the correct message" is and why. Maybe add a more detailed example of several rows and their ids how they should be saved in the database and describe what structure they represent.

Comment: @Progman: yes, it's called nodes. One node has many children.

Comment: The property `Message.Threads` assumes a message can be in multiple `MessageThread` instances. However, by the description it sounds like it belongs to exactly one `MessageThread`. Why do you think you need the `MessageThread` entity`? What are you doing with that entity which can't be represented with `Message` alone? Does it make sense to have `OwnerId` as an optional property in `Message` to make the connection? Are several messages build as a tree like reddit or flat like a forum thread?

Comment: @Progman: An initial message has no *`Owner`*. It can have any number of *responses*, each creates a thread. Any of those responses can have any number of responses ... and so on ... and so on.

Comment: What do you need the `MessageThread` entity for? Why not define a `ParentId` in the `Message` entity, which can be `null` for the initial messages.

Comment: @Progman: I've done this as a work around. I expect at some point to add configurations to the `MessageThread` similar to how Twitter allows an OP to determine who can comment, visibility, etc.